# Git: Using a Makefile in untracked build directory

Tags: git, makefile

I'm writing a C++ application that has source files in a `source` directory, within which there is a `build` directory. The `build` directory contains the `Makefile`, so when I build the program I do so from the build directory.

I want `git` to ignore the `build` directory because it doesn't contain source files. However, I do want git to track the `Makefile`. What's the best practice for tracking the `Makefile` but ignoring the other build files? Should I be using another directory structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell git to **not** ignore certain files in `.gitignore` by prepending `!` to a pattern. So you could put a `.gitignore` file in your `build` directory with content like this:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file and the Makefile
!.gitignore
!Makefile
```

To give credit where I think credit is due, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982/3342206) is probably where I first learned about these exceptions.

Comment: Ah, I had been using my root-level .gitignore to ignore the whole build directory, so I was having trouble telling git not to ignore the Makefile within the build directory. The separate .gitignore file solves it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore rules are just for file git does not already know about, and you can also `git add` any file by specifying it's name.

So, just git add the Makefile, and add an ignore rule to ignore build/

You could place a `.gitignore` file in `build/` with pattern `*`

Comment: While this answer is entirely correct, it does not address the problem of an accidental deletion of the Makefile, which, if committed, would make it harder to add it again in a subsequent commit. Better be explicit and use a .gitignore exception.

Comment: Well... You can add ignored files just like any other file both from command line and GUIs.